# AndroidRuntime: FatalException:

Tags: android

I really don't know what's happening. On Android Studio every thing is working fine, but when I try to run the app on my phone it gives this error.

```
AndroidRuntime: FatalException:
Process: com.example.vb.textreader, PID: 29524
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vb.textreader/com.example.vb.textreader.ocrcapture}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.example.vb.textreader.CameraSourcePreview
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.example.vb.textreader.CameraSourcePreview
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.vb.textreader.ocrcapture.onCreate(ocrcapture.java:67)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.vb.textreader.CameraSourcePreview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.vb.textreader-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:575)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.vb.textreader.ocrcapture.onCreate(ocrcapture.java:67) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.vb.textreader.CameraSourcePreview" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_932ddf769cdf6f7ff910db3bda1b13074bfa8aca-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_ed28e3a48cbb17d2b91d4065fb1975ae0dafdc68-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.vb.textreader/fil
```

I am trying to create an OCR app on android. There is no error in the code as viewed in Android Studio. Any help is greatly appreciated.

XML Code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<com.example.vb.textreader.proprietary.CameraSourcePreview
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.vb.textreader.GraphicOverlay
        android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.example.vb.textreader.proprietary.CameraSourcePreview>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout you're trying to inflate when this error occurs? Most likely you're using a custom view (com.example.vb.textreader.CameraSourcePreview) which does not exist in this package.

Comment: yes, the layout xml you're trying to inflate, most probably when calling setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_here)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a custom view **com.example.vb.textreader.CameraSourcePreview** that's used in a XML layout file that's causing the problem.

Check it's attributes and implementation. if it depends on a library, check the dependencies in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use `com.example.vb.textreader.CameraSourcePreview` which must be a custom view you implemented. One thing that comes to my mind is to check to see if the custom view resides exactly at that location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the provided solution is related to your issue but 
try to`compile 'com.android.support:design:*****'` instead of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:*****`